# Regular expression matching both conditions but on separate parts of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regexes:

1. `([JQKA])\1`
2. `([2-9TJQKA])\1`

I would like to check string with length of 5 if both of regexes matches together - but on separate characters.

So:

If I have a string of `2233` - **it should not match** because it does not meet condition of *Regex 1* and is meeting condition of *Regex 2*

If I have a string of `33QQ2` - **it should match** because `QQ` matches *Regex 1* and `33` matches *Regex 2*

If I have a string `AQQ44` - **it should match** because `QQ` *Regex 1* and `44` matches *Regex 2*

If I have a string `AAKQQ` - **it should match** because `AA` *Regex 1* and `QQ` matches *Regex 2*

If I have a string `QQ234` - **it should not match**. Even when it matches Regex 1 and Regex 2 condition with same `QQ`, I want second condition to validate other part of string than first so after it matches Regex 1 - it does not find part that match Regex 2.

Comment: What are the backreferences for in your expressions?

Comment: in both example 1. and 2. - the '\1'

Comment: This is not going to be pretty: `^(?=.{5}$).*(?:([JQKA])\1.*([2-9TJQKA])\2|([2-9TJQKA])\3.*([JQKA])\4)`

Comment: @RobertAndrosz - I know what they are. The question is what are they *for*? (I think the answer is: So that QQ matches but QJ doesn't...)

Comment: Yes T.J, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?=.{5}$).*(?:([JQKA])\1.*([2-9TJQKA])\2|([2-9TJQKA])\3.*([JQKA])\4)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ifNtsg/1). You may replace `.` in the lookahead pattern with `[A-Z0-9]` if you only allow uppercase letters or digits in the string (i.e. `(?=.{5}$)` => `(?=[A-Z0-9]{5}$)`).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{5}$)` - total string length must be 5 chars other than line break chars
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:([JQKA])\1.*([2-9TJQKA])\2|([2-9TJQKA])\3.*([JQKA])\4)` - a non-capturing group matching either of

  - `([JQKA])\1.*([2-9TJQKA])\2` - Pattern 1 followed with any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible and the Pattern 2
  - `|` - or
  - `([2-9TJQKA])\3.*([JQKA])\4` - Pattern 2 followed with any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible and the Pattern 1

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. It helps a lot. After validating I have one issue which i did not oversee. If `([2-9TJQKA])\1` happens twice - it also should validate TRUE even if the first one does not match. Than I edit first occurance - and it works. `^(?=.{5}$).*(?:([2-9TJQKA])\1.*([2-9TJQKA])\2|([2-9TJQKA])\3.*([JQKA])\4)`